# Can stonebows fire alchemical sling bullets and alchemist's bullets?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, weapons

Now I'm like 90% sure this is a yes but i wanted to double check, because i kinda realized that an alchemist with a stonebow, rapid reload and concentrated splash can lob sling bullets filled with alchemical liquids for their damage plus 1.5 times their intelligence modifier on a full attack.

So best case, hybridized Artokus's fire + Mineral Acid for 6d6+1.5 int with concentrated splash.
I just want double check to make sure this is legit.

Answer (score 3):

### This should work

[Stone Bows](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/stonebow/) can fire sling bullets.

> Instead of bolts, the stonebow shoots sling bullets.

An [alchemist's bullet](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/specific-magic-weapons/alchemist-s-bullet/) is a magic item that also counts as a sling bullet

> This +1 **sling bullet** contains a magical reservoir that can store a single vial of any alchemical substance

So yes, stone bows can fire alchemist's bullets. If you take additional feats like Rapid Reload they will work as usual. And if you take [Concentrated Splash](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/concentrated-splash-combat), you can opt to deal 50% extra damage to the target, instead of causing splash damage

> the damage dealt to the target of the direct hit increases by 50%

All that seems legitimate.